# REST API - Error 400 - opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to add a flow using REST API in ODL but I am getting the following error:

{"errors":{"error":[{"error-type":"protocol","error-tag":"malformed-message","error-message":"Error parsing input: Child \"flow\" was not found in parent schema node

The flow rule is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow>
<priority>2</priority>
<flow-name>Foo</flow-name>
<match>
    <ethernet-match>
        <ethernet-type>
            <type>2048</type>
        </ethernet-type>
    </ethernet-match>
    <ipv4-destination>10.0.10.2/24</ipv4-destination>
</match>
<id>1</id>
<table_id>0</table_id>
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <order>0</order>
        <apply-actions>
            <action>
               <order>0</order>
               <dec-nw-ttl/>
            </action>
        </apply-actions>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</flow>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

the flow looks right to me. just for reference, here is a similar
flow that we use in upstream ODL testing that works.

what is the URL of the REST call you are using? Maybe you are sending
it to a slightly wrong URL.

Here's a [link](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/user-guide/openflow-plugin-project-user-guide.html?highlight=end%20to%20end%20flows#end-to-end-flows) to the openflowplugin user guide for pushing flows.
Actually, now that I looked, it seems that might be exactly where you
took your flow from. So, back to the question of the endpoint you are
using.

Comment: I am using this address:        http://localhost:8080/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:1/table/0/flow/125/

Comment: is it because the flow id in your XML (1) and URL (125) don't match?